# Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'app.js' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, node.js

every time I launch my nodejs server, there is this error that appears

Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'app.js' in 'where clause'

````
    connection.query('select * from products', (erreur,resultat)=>{
    if(erreur) throw erreur;
    return res.render('produits/index', { produits : resultat});

    });
})

server.get('/produits/:id',(req,res)=>{
    connection.query(`select * from products where id=${req.params.id}`, (erreur,resultat)=>{
      if(erreur) throw erreur

      return res.render("produits/detail", { produit : resultat[0] })
    })
})```
````

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: You are opening yourself to [SQL injection attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) by taking a parameter from the URL and directly passing it to your query.

Comment: The error indicates that the value of `req.params.id` is `app.js`, not an ID. Use `console.log(req.params);` to see what you're getting.